# What is the set $g^{-1}([-1,1])$?

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $g(x,y)=xy$ for $xy\in \mathbb R$.

What is $g^{-1}([-1,1])$?

I know that $g^{-1}([-1,1])=\{{(x,y) \,:\    g(x,y)\in [-1,1]}\}$.

But finding all values $(x,y)$ is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Are you familiar with the process of "accepting" an answer?.  Of course you can upvote any/all answers you find helpful (that's what the gray uparrow and downarrow are found.)  However, when you ask a question and you find one answer that helps you the most, you can, in addition  to upvoting it, click on the gray tick mark $\Large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer. It turns green when you do so.

Answer (score 3):

It is confusing. The question is what to do with this set:
$$
\{ (x,y) \mid g(x,y) \in [-1,1]\}
$$
What we want to do is describe what this set is. So we can replace $g(x,y)$ with its definition. Then we want to describe all points $(x,y)$ such that
$$
xy \in [-1,1]
$$
that is, $-1 \le xy \le 1$.

You could stop right here: "it's the set of points $(x,y)$ such that $-1 \le xy \le 1$". But, they probably want you to *draw* this set.
So we can draw the set by first drawing the points $(x,y)$ where $xy = 1$ and where $xy = -1$.
Then the set of points $(x,y)$ is going to have these lines as a boundary.

So we can draw $y = \frac{1}{x}$, and then draw $y = \frac{-1}{x}$, and then we need to shade the points that are between those two. Try out some points and you will see that anything in-between, such as $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(-1,0)$, $(1/2, -1/2)$ is part of the set where $-1 \le xy \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Graph $y=\frac1x $ and $y=-\frac1x $ and then shade in the sort of four -pronged region in between. ..